# How to use pass access token for using Rest Api in Jira Server after generating oauth access token. Using Nodejs(request library)

Tags: node.js, oauth, request, jira, jira-rest-api

```js
request.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project',
    {
        oauth:{
            consumer_key:consumer_key,
            consumer_secret:consumer_secret,
            oauth_signature_method: RSA-SHA1,
            token: oauth_access_token,
            token_secret: oauth_access_token_secret
        },
        qs:{user_id:user_id} // or screen_name
    },
    function (err, res, body) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(body)
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The oauth access token can be passed in the following way in the get request being made

```
request.get('http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project', {
  'auth': {
    'bearer': oauth_access_token
  },
 'qs':{user_id:user_id} // or screen_name
}, function (error, response, body) {
   // Do more stuff with 'body' here
})
```

Comment: i am getting empty array ([ ]) in body.even though i have project in jira

Comment: can you also log the other parameters..
console.log(error, response, body);

inside the function

Comment: Also, make sure the server is running on port 8080 for jira project

Comment: JIra is running on 8080 and i logged all 3 . I got error : null body: [ ] and respnse i got the entire resp object with body:  []

Comment: debug the jira server and put logs in /rest/api/2/project endpoint to check what processing is happening there...
maybe your user_id related data processing is returning [] empty result.

Comment: as far as request and oauth is concerned, there is no error means oauth part was a success.